# plot average value every 30 minutes

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, plot

I am trying to plot the average value of "Spread" every 30 minutes. My data look like this

```
                        Bid      Ask    Spread     relative_spread       relative_quoted_half_spread
Date
2021-02-01 00:01:02  1.21291  1.21336  0.00045         0.000371                     0.000185
2021-02-01 00:01:21  1.21290  1.21336  0.00046         0.000379                     0.000190
2021-02-01 00:01:31  1.21287  1.21336  0.00049         0.000404                     0.000202
2021-02-01 00:01:32  1.21290  1.21336  0.00046         0.000379                     0.000190
2021-02-01 00:02:08  1.21290  1.21338  0.00048         0.000396                     0.000198
```

My first attempt is

```
plt.figure('Average spread over time')
minutes_dfs = df.resample('30M').mean()
print(Date)

ax3 = minutes_dfs.plot(x='Date', y='Spread',ls='-',color='k')
ax3.set_title('Spread introday every 30mins')
ax3.set_ylabel('Spread change')
ax3.legend(loc='best')
ax3.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

I got an error message as "Exception has occurred: KeyError 'Date'"
However, I have tried this before I plot

```
print(Date)
```

I got the Date column results like this

```
0       2021-02-01 00:01:02
1       2021-02-01 00:01:21
2       2021-02-01 00:01:31
3       2021-02-01 00:01:32
4       2021-02-01 00:02:08
```

My second try is

```
plt.figure('Average spread over time')
minutes_dfs = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'Date', freq='30M')).mean()
print(Date)

ax3 = minutes_dfs.plot(x='Date', y='Spread',ls='-',color='k')
ax3.set_title('Spread introday every 30mins')
ax3.set_ylabel('Spread change')
ax3.legend(loc='best')
ax3.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

and then I got an error message like this
'The grouper name Date is not found'

Does anyone know where did I go wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Because `Date` is index need remove `x`:

```
x3 = minutes_dfs.plot(y='Spread',ls='-',color='k')
```

Or add `reset_index`:

```
x3 = minutes_dfs.reset_index().plot(x='Date', y='Spread',ls='-',color='k')
```

In second solution is removed `key` parameter, because `DatetimeIndex`:

```
minutes_dfs = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='30M')).mean()

x3 = minutes_dfs.plot(y='Spread',ls='-',color='k')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried both solutions, however, by removing the 'Date', the x-axis then starts from 2019 until 2023 in years. My data only has one-day-only data.

Comment: @ jezrael yep, I tried this also ** df  = df.set_index('Date') # Set index as Date** to set the index.

Comment: @Susie - So your problem is in data are datetimes from `2019` to `2023` and are ploting? Not understand.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Yes, it should not be from 2019 to 2023. I also tried `print (ax3.index)` and I got an error message as`'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'index'` .

Comment: @Susie - So if not data from `2019` to `2023` what need? Problem is need filter data? Because in your file is many years?

Comment: because my data only has in one day, not many years. so when I plot the Spread it should match with the related Date. I named as "Date" but it actually is the time of the day.

Comment: `Spread it should match with the related Date.` - So if resample by 30 minutes, it is expected if axix is by date and time. Still not undertand. Is possible see how looks your plot with real data and then explian what need?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230110/discussion-between-susie-and-jezrael).